# How to I marry Scrapy and Selenium to scroll down this webpage and scrape all the text?

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

So the reason I'm using both is because I have other functions written in my Scrapy class already but I'm left with scrolling (hence Selenium) and scraping all the text in this webpage

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which
import time

class ActSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ACT'
    allowed_domains = ['sso.agc.gov.sg']
    start_urls = [
        'https://sso.agc.gov.sg/Act/AA2004'
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

        chrome_path = which('chromedriver')

        driver =  webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path,  options=chrome_options)
        driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
        driver.get("https://sso.agc.gov.sg/Act/AA2004")

        #insert scroller function?

        self.html = driver.page_source 
        driver.close()

    def parse(self, response):
        resp = Selector(text=self.html)
        for table in resp.xpath("//div[@class='body']"):
            yield {
                'info': table.xpath('.//table/text()').getall()
            }
```

I have found a number of infinite scrollers with Selenium but am unsure how to deploy it in the scrapy class to work.

Comment: do you get error message? always put full error message (starting atword "Taceback") in question (notcomment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: The indentation would fail:   `def __init__(self):` is indented to `class ActSpider(scrapy.Spider):`

Comment: My bad! Edited the indentation mistake